# Android emulator crashes with glMatrixMode:1543 GL err 0x500

Tags: android

On a Windows 10 running in Parallels on a Mac, the android emulator crashes while launching

```
C:\Android-SDK>.\tools\bin\avdmanager create avd --name GeneXus-API16-ARM --package system-images;android-16;default;armeabi-v7a
Auto-selecting single ABI armeabi-v7a===] 100% Fetch remote repository...
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no]
C:\Android-SDK>emulator.exe -avd GeneXus-API16-ARM
glMatrixMode:1543 GL err 0x500
```

The first lines of the dump are as follows

> Version:1.0 StartHTML:0000000107 EndHTML:0000846337
>   StartFragment:0000000538 EndFragment:0000846301 Operating system:
>   Windows NT
>   10.0.16299 CPU: x86 GenuineIntel family 6 model 70 stepping 1 6 CPUs Crash reason: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ Crash address: 0x0
>   Assertion: Unknown assertion type 0x00000000 Process uptime: not
>   available Thread 21 (crashed) [SNIP] Found by: given as instruction
>   pointer in context Stack contents: [SNIP] Possible instruction
>   pointers: 1 libGLES_CM_translator.DLL + 0x16a70 eip = 0x69dd6a70 esp =
>   0x2a61e398 ebp = 0x2a61e400 Found by: previous frame's frame pointer

This happens with:

- Android SDK Tools 26.0.2
- Android SDK Platform-tools 23.1
- Android Emulator 27.0.5
- Android SDK Build-tools 26.0.2
- Android 4.1 (API 16) ARM EABI v7a System Image

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to launch the emulator with no GPU as follows

```
C:\Android-SDK\emulator>emulator.exe -avd GeneXus-API16-ARM -gpu off
```

Now, in some cases you may experience that the emulator launches too slowly or does not launch at al.. In that case, open
c:\users\.android\avd\GeneXus-API16-ARM.avd\config.ini
and replace its content with these settings

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
abi.type=armeabi-v7a
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Nexus S
hw.gps=yes
hw.keyboard=no
hw.lcd.density=160
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=1500
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-16\default\armeabi-v7a\
sdcard.size=200M
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=480x800
skin.path=480x800
tag.display=
tag.id=default
```

Now run again

```
C:\Android-SDK\emulator>emulator.exe -avd GeneXus-API16-ARM -gpu off
```

or

```
C:\Android-SDK\emulator>emulator.exe -avd GeneXus-API16-ARM -gpu off -accel auto -no-boot-anim -screen multi-touch
```